# How can I add attribute runat="server" in javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, runatserver

I want to dynamic create element in js but I cant add runat="server",How can i do

```
var btn = document.createElement('button');
                    btn.setAttribute('class', 'glyphicon glyphicon-usd btn btn-info text-uppercase');
                    btn.setAttribute('style', 'float:right');
                    btn.setAttribute('onserverclick', 'blessbuttonMaster_Click');
                    btn.setAttribute('id', 'reply_' + data[i].ID);
                    btn.setAttribute("runat","server");
```

Comment: You can't. Javascript runs on the client, and you can only create client controls in the HTML DOM that is already loaded. A server control needs to exist on the server.

Comment: @AlpBlo It is not how ASP.NET WebForm works. What are you trying to achieve besides adding button at client-side?

Comment: Useful link : https://msdn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/library/7a9d6h4f(v=vs.100).aspx